# How to debug big redirect chain in nginx. Unexpected redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, 301-redirect

I have a task to make a large site migration now. And i have a large number of redirects in config. 
But I cannot understand why one redirect causing second redirect in chain. Even if any other redirects commented/disabled.

So my config for location:

```
server {

...
index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~* /index.php {
    if ($args ~ "^page=flights&start_city=([\+\w\d\s]*)(&.*)?$"){
        return 301 $scheme://$server_name/flights?departure_city=$arg_start_city;
    }
    if ($is_args){
        return 301 $scheme://$server_name/$1;
    }

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

What do I expect?
I expect that old links like

```
https://example.com/index.php?page=flights&start_city=Berlin&s_loc_lat=&s_loc_long=
```

Become:

```
https://example.com/flights?departure_city=Berlin
```

And at the same time links like:

```
https://example.com/index.php?someoldpar=someoldkey&someoldpar2=someoldkey2
```

Become:

```
    https://example.com/
```

What I got when testing this config?

. I got this redirection chain for first link:

```
 1. GET https://example.com/index.php?page=flights&start_city=Berlin&s_loc_lat=&s_loc_long=
 2. 301 https://example.com/flights?departure_city=Berlin
 3. 301 https://example.com/
```

How to exclude step 3 for links that already redirected?
Lavarel under backend.

Comment: Without:
`    if ($is_args){
        return 301 $scheme://$server_name/$1;
    }`
Redirects works, but catching of all other requests not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `try_files` statement rewrites the URI to `/index.php` and appends the query string. Your `if ($is_args)` statement redirects any URI with a query string. You have a redirection loop.

The `location ~* /index.php` block cannot differentiate between an original request containing `index.php` and the result of the `try_files` default.

You should perform your tests on the `$request_uri` variable, which will always contain the original request together with the query string. You can use an `if` or a `map`. With more than a few regular expressions, a `map` is the preferred solution.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default 0;
    ~^/index.php\?page=flights&start_city=(?<startcity>[\+\w\d\s]*)(&.*)?$ /flights?departure_city=$startcity;
    ~^/index.php\?                                                         /;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($redirect) {
        return 301 $redirect;
    }
```

You can remove your `location ~* /index.php` block, as it's no longer required.
Regular expressions are evaluated in order until a matching rule is found, so order the rules with most specific first and least specific last.
Use named captures, as the numeric captures can go out of scope.
You do not need to specify the scheme or domain name if they are the same.
The `map` directive sits outside of the `server block. 
See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.